# Selenium IDE: How to check text color using CSS

Tags: css, ide, selenium

I have a link:

`<a class="title">My link</a>`

It is styled with this CSS code:

```
a.title {
  color: #CC3333;
}
```

How can I verify that the text "My link" is red? I can locate the element with `css=a.title`, but how can I assert that `color == "#CC3333"` in Selenium IDE?

Comment: Or how can I find this locator by color (color: #CC3333;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`style.color` will return color if actual DOM element has `style` attribute. In your case, when color is definied in `<style>` tag it won't work. This we need you use `getComputedStyle()`. Still, `color` returns color in RGB format but you may convert your color [manually](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php) and verify RGB result.

Like this:

```
assertEval(
  "window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0]).getPropertyValue('color')",
  "rgb(204, 51, 51)"
)
```

N.B. It's also recommended to use `selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()` instead of `window`. I left window to make snippet shorter.

Comment: I input "assertEval" to command and "("window.document.getElementsByClassName('post-tag')[0].style.color", "#CC3333")" to target, but it's doesn't work. "[error] locator not found: window.document.getElementsByClassName('post-tag')[0].style.color", "#CC3333"

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten to change example class to yours. See updated comment.

Comment: He even can't find locator "dom=document.getElementClassName('title')" and "window.document.getElementsByClassName('title')" can't find too

Comment: In case your link has class `title` it should. Try to locate the element by `dom=document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0]`. Also try the following `storeEval("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].style.color", color`) and the `echo(${color})`

Comment: Yes, "dom=document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0]" is true locator. But: command: storeEval Target:selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementsByClassNa‌​me('title')[0].style.color", color - it doesn't work. Maybe we can talk about this in Skype, if you do not mind, of course

Comment: Not needed. My fault, I though `style.color` will return color even if it's set in CSS file or `<style>` tag. But it didn't. I just tested updated answer and it works for me.